# Draw sine wave with frequency?

Tags: swift, uibezierpath

I am drawing one period of a sine wave with:

```
let width = rect.width
let height = rect.height

let origin = CGPoint(x: width * (1 - graphWidth) / 2, y: height * 0.50)

let path = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: origin)

for angle in stride(from: 5.0, through: 360.0, by: 5.0) {
    let x = origin.x + CGFloat(angle/360.0) * width * graphWidth
    let y = origin.y - CGFloat(sin(angle/180.0 * Double.pi)) * height * amplitude
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
}

Globals.sharedInstance.palleteGlowGreen.setStroke()
path.stroke()
```

How would I:

1. Draw multiple periods for the same width (now its 0-360)
2. Change number 1 (num of periods) dynamically so you see the wave squeezing.

Comment: This is more a question about math than about Swift, isn't it? – You'll have to insert a factor in the argument of the sine, e.g. `sin(2*angle/180.0 * Double.pi)`. You might then need to adjust the increment of the loop.

Comment: A factor of 2 just change the amplitude , anyway, part to of the question is a swift subject since I would like to change a current draw continuously .

Comment: You have to add the factor to the *argument* of the sine, that should change the frequency.

Comment: Wow, @Curnelious.  That code looks really familiar. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40230696/1630618.  How about an up vote?

Comment: @vacawama yes i took it from github, is it morally wrong to copy code from the internet today?  Do i have to declare it and make a statement?

Comment: Sorry Curnelious, you did nothing wrong. My frustration is with the author of the other question. Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: @Curnelious - On Stack Overflow, "user contributions licensed under [cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)". So the author of that github violated the ToS when they took vacawama's code without attribution. (At the very least, it's seriously uncool.) In your case, as practical matter, if you're posting a question using someone else's code, you should share where you got it from. It's the right thing to do and plus sometimes it helps us answer your question better.

Comment: @Rob thanks for your comment, I appreciate very much the help and knowledge of many people here, but I think in general developers should take it easy, It sometimes feels that programmers tend to be childish and give too much importance for unimportant things. Its not that somebody steal a patented algorithm, usually code is not belong to someone, because in general its the same with only some degree of difference. Telling the world these 5 lines of code are from developer X, will not benefit him at all, because its not some innovative genius AI algorithm he invented,its an API. Anyway thanks.

Comment: Lol. You asked us the "is it morally wrong" question, so don't get churlish when you don't like the answer. Stack Overflow's user contribution licenses are so simple and clear, so while I get what you're saying, I just don't understand why you wouldn't attribute the original author. It's simple. It's the right thing to do. And links back to the original code sample can sometimes even help us better understand/answer the question.

Comment: I was cynical regarding the morality.  "Stack Overflow's user contribution licenses" , are you series ? in the last 20 years I had never read manual, and thats of course including my iPhone, so reading and following a website manual - thats exactly what I was talking about. Take it easy, life is bigger then a few lines of machine code.

Comment: Please take it easy, if you invest 30 minutes only to get a recognition or a thank you, you are going to be very sad, because there are many people in this world that don't care. So if its you, thanks a lot for the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just multiply the `angle` by `periods`:

```
@IBDesignable
class SineWaveView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable
    var graphWidth: CGFloat = 0.90  { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }

    @IBInspectable
    var amplitude: CGFloat = 0.20   { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }

    @IBInspectable
    var periods: CGFloat = 1.0      { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let width = bounds.width
        let height = bounds.height

        let origin = CGPoint(x: width * (1 - graphWidth) / 2, y: height * 0.50)

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: origin)

        for angle in stride(from: 5.0, through: 360.0 * periods, by: 5.0) {
            let x = origin.x + angle/(360.0 * periods) * width * graphWidth
            let y = origin.y - sin(angle/180.0 * .pi) * height * amplitude
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
        }

        Globals.sharedInstance.palleteGlowGreen.setStroke()
        path.stroke()
    }

}
```

By the way, by making a change in `periods` call `setNeedsDisplay`, that means that when you update `periods`, the graph will be automatically redrawn.

---

And, rather than iterating through degrees, but then converting everything back to radians, I might just stay in radians:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let width = bounds.width
    let height = bounds.height

    let origin = CGPoint(x: width * (1 - graphWidth) / 2, y: height * 0.50)
    let maxAngle: CGFloat = 2 * .pi * periods
    let iterations = Int(min(1000, 100 * periods))

    let point = { (angle: CGFloat) -> CGPoint in
        let x = origin.x + angle/maxAngle * width * self.graphWidth
        let y = origin.y - sin(angle) * height * self.amplitude
        return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    }

    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: point(0))

    for i in 1 ... iterations {
        path.addLine(to: point(maxAngle * CGFloat(i) / CGFloat(iterations)))
    }

    Globals.sharedInstance.palleteGlowGreen.setStroke()
    path.stroke()
}
```

Comment: The only possible disadvantage of iterating through radians is that – due to the limited precision of the floating point values – the last value `maxAngle` might not be covered, making the graph a tiny bit too short.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. You probably shouldn't `stride` through any floating point variable at all (or if you did, stride `to`, not `through` and add last point yourself). It's probably easiest to just iterate through some integer range.