# IOS: Dynamically draw shape with wave divider in Swift (Bezier Curve)

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, bezier

Initially I have 2 backgrounds images (I use here 2 rectangles for simplicity, a green one  and a grey one) the rectangles height is dynamically adjustable and I need to draw the black wave divider (also a custom image with gradient) between them as you can see in the image. I've tried to simply crop the backgrounds with the divider and merge them, but because the height (first rectangle will have a different height than the second one) is adjustable it will mess up the wave divider. It is not enough to draw the divider, also the rectangles should be cropped to match the divider form. Everything should be done programmatically in Swift and a pdf document will be generated in the end. I can only think to Bezier Curve (CGMutablePath, UIBezierPath), but I don't know exactly how to achieve it. Thanks a lot!

[image: Shape I need to obtain]

```
           Shape I need to obtain
```

[image: Grey rectangle]

```
       Grey Rectangle
```

[image: Green Rectangle]

```
         Green rectangle
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us your code?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40411198/draw-sine-wave-with-frequency