# Draw waves between 2 points with UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, drawing, uibezierpath

I'm trying to give a UITableViewCell a 'waved' bottom to make it look like a 'ripped off paper' effect (for an order receipt).
I want to draw this over the whole length of the cell.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40230696/2399348) solution on StackOverflow, which creates one single sine between two points.

I tried altering that code to make the effect I need (I know there's a lot wrong in my code):

```
    let path = UIBezierPath()
     let origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: bounds.size.height / 2)
     path.move(to: origin)

      let graphWidth: CGFloat = 0.8  // Graph is 80% of the width of the view
     let amplitude: CGFloat = 0.5   // Amplitude of sine wave is 30% of view

     for angle in stride(from: 1.0, through: bounds.size.width * 5.0, by: 1.0) {
         let x = origin.x + CGFloat(angle/360.0) * bounds.size.width * (360 / (bounds.size.width * 10.0))
         let y = origin.y - CGFloat(sin(angle/180.0 * CGFloat.pi)) * bounds.size.height * amplitude * (360 / (bounds.size.width * 10.0))
         path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
     }
```

What I'm trying to reach is:
[image: wave]

What would be the best approach here? If I could get above solution working and looking like the image, that would be perfect. If anyone has other suggestions, I'm open to everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All credit to [vacawama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630618/vacawama) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40230696/2395636). You can achieve this as below,

```
class SineView: UIView {
    let graphWidth: CGFloat = 0.15
    let amplitude: CGFloat = 0.1

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let width = rect.width
        let height = rect.height

        let origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: height * 0.50)

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: origin)

        var endY: CGFloat = 0.0
        let step = 5.0
        for angle in stride(from: step, through: Double(width) * (step * step), by: step) {
            let x = origin.x + CGFloat(angle/360.0) * width * graphWidth
            let y = origin.y - CGFloat(sin(angle/180.0 * Double.pi)) * height * amplitude
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
            endY = y
        }
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: endY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: origin.y))

        UIColor.black.setFill()
        path.fill()
        UIColor.black.setStroke()
        path.stroke()
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let size = view.frame.size
        let sineView = SineView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: size.width, height: 60))
        sineView.backgroundColor = .white
        self.view.addSubview(sineView)
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

You can play with the `graphWidth` and `amplitude` to adjust the graph as you like.