# checking that the CAShapeLayer is in UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem. I created sinusoide using code: [sinusoide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230312/how-do-i-draw-a-cosine-or-sine-curve-in-swift) and increased the thickness with path.lineWidth. I also added a dot to the screen (CAShapeLayer). I need to check if my dot is in the sinusoidal. I checked the available function UIBezierPath.contain. Unfortunately, it does not considering the lineWidth. I also checked by color if the pixel on the screen contains color but unfortunately it is very slow and takes 100% CPU. Whether there is any other quick way to find out if the dot is in the  UIBezierPath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`copy(strokingWithWidth:lineCap:lineJoin:miterLimit:transform:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgpath/2427133-copy) to create a stroked copy of the path. Then use [`contains`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgpath/2427117-contains) on the copy to test the center of the dot.